# node.js I need to be able to create a brand new JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I am trying to create a new JSON file. Whenever I try to use the writeFile function, it just says there is no such directory open.
This is the code I've tried.

```
fs.writeFile('./UserData/' + msg.author + ".json", JSON.stringify({firstSplitContent: firstSplit,secondSplitContent: secondSplit,thirdSplitContent: thirdSplit,fourthSplitContent: fourthSplit,fifthSplitContent: fifthSplit},null,4), err => {
          if(err) throw err;
          console.log("File is created successfully.")
        });
```

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './UserData/<@301910353967710208>.json'

help would be appreciated. Yes I know that windows wont use those special characters. I switched it to author.id to remove.

Comment: It's hard to read, but am I reading the code correctly that you are doing `JSON.stringify({...}, null, 4)` ? Edit: Nvm, those are documented optional arguments

Comment: The json.stringify got long. Haven't found an easier way to pass it into the write function. But fs is still confusing as I haven't ever used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` won't create any directories that don't already exist.

I suspect that the directory in your path, `UserData`, doesn't exist, which is why you are getting that error.

Otherwise, your path may be wrong. Since you are using a relative path, the code will look for the `UserData` folder **in the working directory**, ie. where the code is currently executing.

If the path is correct, try creating it first:

```
if(!fs.existsSync('./UserData') {
  fs.mkdirSync('./UserData')
}
```

Or, you could use a package such as `fs-extra` that gives you the capability of creating any folders in the path that don't already exist.

This is probably the most relevant function to you, if you want to use `fs-extra`:
https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/outputJson.md

Comment: Great answer! Couldn't have explained it any better

Comment: The folder exists. But is there similar a similar function for creating a json file then?

Comment: No, you've done it right - create the object, JSON.stringify it and then write it to a file with the .json extension.

Can I suggest you create the object separately, then just pass the object to the stringify object? You could define it over multiple lines with proper indenting, and your code would be much easier to read

Comment: Also, if the folder exists - are you in the right directory? Since you have used a relative path, the code will look for the `UserData` folder in the directory **where the code is currently executing**. 

Try using an absolute path, or executing from the directory that UserData is located in.

Comment: The path really wasn't the problem. It was some old code doing "something", still not sure. Anyways the fs-extra module worked exactly how I needed it to! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the answer of Willianm but just one thing I noticed: You are trying to use `msg.author` in your file name, but that's an object (a really big object), you might want to consider changing it to `message.author.id`